# Ignore unit test: cannot find Symbol

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am trying to ignore a unit test, I have a test class similar to

```
@Test
public void testSomething() throws Exception {

  testcode

}
```

When I put `@Ignore` above `@Test` the execution fails with message

> error: cannot find symbol

What is the correct way to ignore a test?

Comment: Did you import the annotation?

Comment: Is that your only test in this class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `import org.junit.Ignore;` as import statement

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem because of my typo "Ingore" in the import statement :)